# Git - get list of all commits which changed a file

Tags: git

I try to get a list of all commits which made changes to a certain file. Is this possible? It should be sorted by date.

```
git showAllChanges /path/to/file.xy
```

Output:

```
d9fc62dba13069fc281e9d09b698ba2e32f6dafd
2625eb741618dae7004b3d23a5894ae7a91df698
cfae25eced932c1375b3bc56ae8399ca88513d94
```

Comment: use this command: git log -- [filename]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h" -- path/to/file.xy
```

The `--pretty=format:"%h"` allows you to get only minified commit hash. If you want the full hash, you can use `%H`. If you want more you can take a look at the [pretty-formats documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats).

If you want to take filename change into account, you can use the [`--follow`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---follow) option.

Comment: I get `bad revision '%H'

Comment: Could you show me the whole code? I cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you have the `git log` command, as reported in the official [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

By default, with no arguments, git log lists the commits made in that repository in reverse chronological order; that is, the most recent commits show up first.

You can also pretty print the output with `$ git log --pretty=oneline` or `$ git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"`

Or limit time interval with `git log --since=2.weeks`.

There are a lot of parameters, check out the manual page. [Here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) is the full documentation

Comment: But this does not answer how to only view a specific file

Comment: I've updated the answer, but basically you have to write `git log [--] <path>`